# Overloaded == and != operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

**I made some of the updates as requested and added the output pic. thanks again everyone**

**Thanks again everyone!!**

I'm sorry in advance to all the moderators out there you're going to hate my question. I've tried to read though some of the examples on here and I'm not getting it. I have a project due tomorrow and these are the overloaded operators I'm having trouble with. The professor says the problem is in my if statements but wont tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
    bool MyString::operator==(const MyString &right) const
{
    if (strlen(m_pString) != strlen(right.m_pString))
        {
            return false;
        }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(m_pString); ++i)
    {
        if (m_pString[i] == right.m_pString[i])
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

        return true;
}





bool MyString::operator!=(const MyString &right) const
{
    if (strlen(m_pString) != strlen(right.m_pString))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(m_pString); ++i)
    {
        if (m_pString[i] != right.m_pString[i])
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Here are the guidelines for reference:

**Overloaded equal relational operator ( operator== )**

A == B

The equal relational operator is used to determine if two MyString objects are equal. This should compare each character in both objects m_pString to verify that both null terminated strings are identical. This should return a true if the strings are identical and a false, if not.

**Overloaded not equal relational operator ( operator!= )**

A != B

The not equal relational operator is used to determine if two MyString objects are not equal. This should compare each character in both objects m_pString. It should return a true immediately if and when a character does not match. This should return a false if the strings are the same.

From what I understand this code should do just that. VB isn't flagging any warning or errors. Thanks you in advance for any input on what's wrong with my IF statements.

[This is a picture of the Failed out put from the driver program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFShc.jpg)

Comment: You have several bugs - step through the code in your debugger for different test cases and you should soon see the problems.

Comment: Just want to point out, you don't need `strlen`. Combining the length counting and character comparisons into one single loop makes things simpler and faster.

Comment: Read about `strcmp`. And the usual implementation of `a != b` is simply `!(a == b)`.

Comment: Tell me: what do you expect `if (m_pString[i] == strlen(right.m_pString))` to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You're comparing the element of `m_pString` with the length of `right.m_pString`.

2.The comparison logic seems wrong.

```
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString &right) const
{
    if (strlen(m_pString) != strlen(right.m_pString))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(m_pString); ++i)
    {
        if (m_pString[i] != right.m_pString[i]) 
        //               ~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        {
            return false;
            //     ~~~~~
        }
    }

    return true;
    //     ~~~~
}
```

3.Don't repeat the similar logic.

```
bool MyString::operator!=(const MyString &right) const
{
    return !operator==(right);
}
```

Comment: This  is what I had before I made the changes to what it currently is. I just changed it back this exact way and it still fails all the test classes

Comment: Unless I've missed something, this code looks correct. Are you sure m_pString is what you expect it is? The constructor for `MyString` could be setting it wrong, or something else could be. Also if you could post some sample output showing it is wrong, or post any error messages, that would help to debug this.

Comment: @MarkJones Could you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the failed test case? First we need to reproduce the problem to solve the issue.

Comment: Oh my != looked nothing like that. I'm not sure about the comparison. I don't think that's the part I'm understanding. From what I understand its checking to see if each character matches and returns true if it does.

Comment: If you `return true`, it finishes the entire function without comparing the rest of the characters. Instead you need to check every character, and then at the very end `return true`. However if you find one that is not equal, you can stop checking and `return false`. (This is the code posted in the answer, in words)

Comment: @MarkJones Your code is checking each character, and return true if they're equal, and left the remainder unchecked. That means, for "abcd" and "aaaa" the result will be true. Is it the request?

Comment: The picture you posted mentions `MyClass`, but your code contains `MyString`. Could this be related to your issue? Maybe I just don't have the right context...

Comment: – songyuanyao
From what I understand the strings have to match to pass.
– Michael Oliver
I noticed that earlier too, Its not motioned anywhere in the project guidelines so I think its just the driver program from and old project he just renamed.

Answer (score 2):

`if (m_pString[i] == strlen(right.m_pString))`

should be:

`if (m_pString[i] == right.m_pString[i])`

You're comparing characters to a string length.

Additionally, in the `==` implementation, you shouldn't be returning true if `m_pString[i] == right.m_pString[i]`. Instead, you need to continue checking all the other characters too, but return false if they are `!=`.

You have a similar issue in your `!=` implementation.

Comment: That's what I had before what's currently there and he said it wasn't correct.

Comment: I added some more to my answer, though you may want to look at @songyuanyao's answer too as it is a little more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your function not only incorrect, but ineffective as well, you call `strlen()` way too many times:

```
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString &right) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; true; ++i)
    {
        if (m_pString[i] != right.m_pString[i] ) 
            return false;
        if (m_pString[i] == 0 )
            return true; 
    }
}
```